# Unable to get IAM security credentials in ECS task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS task that runs an image build from Amazon Linux.

```py
container_pull(
  name = "amazonlinux",
  registry = "registry.hub.docker.com",
  repository = "library/amazonlinux",
  tag = "2022.0.20220315.0",
  digest = "sha256:c74e77c670519cd69e3f5ce3fa714c02c582a40d786dd7e97113e717e7655e4d",
)
```

However when I run the image on ECS and try to perform an operation on S3, I get this error:

> Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.

This surprises me because I thought the image would contain the necessary services to communicate with ECS and obtain IAM credentials.

The role has permissions `s3:PutObject` and `s3:GetObject`.

How do I gain access to S3 inside my image?

---

Note I do not want to pass `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables if I can help it.

Comment: Is this running on EC2 or Fargate?

Comment: It is running on Fargate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I had not assigned a Task Role (I had only assigned an Execution Role).

The Task Role has permission to access S3.